# On how many process do cloud function run?

Tags: firebase, heroku, google-cloud-functions

I would like to use google cloud functions to update an additional database living on heroku because `firebase realtime database` is not cutting it.

However there is a limit of concurrent connections that are accepted on heroku, so I'm wondering how many of them will be opened via cloud functions ? Is it 1 ? Is there no limit ?

I've something  like this in my functions

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';
const pool = new Pool(connectionString);
exports.onAuth = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
  pool.query(...)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions will spin up as many server instances as is required to meet the demand on your functions.  It could be as low as 0 if there is no load, and much higher if there is a lot of load.  Each instance could be doing work for your function.  You can't constrain the number of instances for your functions - it just scales automatically on demand.  So you can think of it as having no limit (as long as you are paying your bills).

Comment: So there is no way to be sure I won't go over limit in my case ?

Comment: Not currently, no.

Comment: It is nowadays possible to limit the maximum number of instances Cloud Functions will spin up: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances