# Is there a way to configure the Google Cloud Function and Pub/Sub parallelism?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Function configured as subscriber of a PubSub topic, my function should invoke another service that have some limitation, but the Function topic consumption is really fast and executes in parallel, what can I do to control the topic consumption frequency? I thought about quotas configuration but it seems too much generic, I would like to configure a specific function as subscriber. Thanks

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46062534/on-how-many-process-do-cloud-function-run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no control over that.  Cloud Functions will always try to react to incoming events as fast as possible, within the limits of the system.

Comment: one important note, I made a mistake, I was handling the exception inside the GF and the messages were removed from the topic, to solve this I let the error blow and the next GF execution deals with this entry.